# call server side function from client side, trigger click is recomended

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have to call server side function from client side,

So instead of creating service and using `ajax` calling it, should we create a server side button and make  `display:none;` and trigger click using jQuery is that recommended?

I have aspx.cs code simple webpage.

Update: I want to store some date - to on server site on page unload event- I am able to get that event, wants to store some info about current user. then page will be close

Comment: You would use AJAX - unless you want to execute a full postback cycle.

Comment: Click? Load? What Event? Clarify your question, show [what you have tried to accomplish](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/). Otherwise, your question will likely be closed.

Comment: Yes you can do this by marking display:none server side button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes why not even you can simply use javascript to call button's click

```
<asp:Button id="buttonid" runat="server" style="display:none" />
```

If you Used Update Panels Then You can Use:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "buttonid.click();", true);
```

Other Wise You can Use

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
        (GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "buttonid.click();",true);
```